# How to check if html element contains every class I specify in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to check if some html element contains three classes, or some of them containts another two with different names.
How can I do that in JavaScript?
If there is not something pure js, then jquery suggestions are welcomed.

I tried matches, but that checks some of them not all
With contains that doesn't work too to check if all of them are on that element :S

```
    for(let i = 0;i < allButtons.length;i++)
    {


          if(allButtons[i].matches('.forwardButton,try') && allButtons[i].disabled == false)
        {
            // // alert("b")
            // if(objectWithSameOrderWhenTheyAreAnswered[`arrayWithSameOrderWhenTheyAreAnswered${answersCounter}`].length != 4)
            // {
            //     objectWithSameOrderWhenTheyAreAnswered[`arrayWithSameOrderWhenTheyAreAnswered${answersCounter}`].push(answers[i])
            // }  
        }
```

Comment: `.forwardButton,.try` one of the two classes -  `.forwardButton.try` both classes

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

console.log(el.classList.contains('class2'));
console.log(el.classList.contains('class3'));
```

```html
<div class="class1 class2 class4"></div>
```